# Applied Geometry: Determining whether a given arc represents a circle or an ellipse

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles, conic-sections

So I am trying to figure out if there is a formula/method for determining whether a given arc is part of an ellipse, or a circle given a chord length (Cl) and height (H).

Ex.

[image]

Now the first arc comes from a unit circle.

The second, visually, at least, is obviously an arc portion of an ellipse.

The third though, is a bit more tricky... It actually still is part of an ellipse, but is a bit more difficult to visualize.

Now, intuitively at least, it seems to me that in the case of the circle, the angle of any portion of that arc should always be constant (?)-- Or, at least, the radius will always be constant for any point along the arc.

The second case could be identified if the radius of any point on the line varies (above ? below ?) the constant that one would find in the case of a circle.

But the third case, I am not so sure...

Further, I am kind of wondering whether or not there is a 'minimum chord length' needed to satisfy said conditions. Again, at least intuitively, it seems if the arc is 'too small' it may be too hard to tell (?)

I say 'applied' in this case because I don't have the formulae for said arcs-- Also, presume arc length (Al) is at least first unknown.

I am working from the impression of drawn arcs, so it *would* be possible for me to find the points, but I'd have to grid out and measure all the points.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For an arc of circle, all normal lines meet at a same point (the centre). This is not true for an ellipse. But in practice all normal lines of an elliptic arc could meet within a very small region.

Comment: Actually, @Intelligentipauca, I thought about your reply, and then wondered 'how many points' to determine a normal (?)-- The obvious answer is 'at least three', and I agree this could serve as a 'unit test'. And also, I am sorry, perhaps I should have asked my question on the 'Physics' forum, because out of millennium, how did Astronomers  observe planets around this world and determine 'it is not in a circle'. Maybe they were lazy and said 'this is the whole orbit'. But your thinking gives me more than enough of a 'bite to chew on', for my purposes. Thanks.

Comment: You should read then Kepler's "Astronomia Nova", as he was the first to conjecture an elliptic shape (for the orbit of Mars, in particular). But he had at his disposal many years of observations.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca the only 'crappy thing' here is I have neither 'years to study', nor an intractable body in motion-- just hand line drawings off a machine (to give you a 'simple' idea', it is any number of screen printing machines-- I mean I *think* these must be completely circular in their motion, but somehow 'if not', my 'big idea' is in a lot of trouble, or just at least can work, just with some refinement). I ask the question, just to 'get out of trouble', before it begins, in a sense.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca, okay so I have already put together this 'basic' animation, that actually does not even include 'what I want to do'. Even that, in itself is a *much  harder* challenge. But in this exercise I am assuming most presses are based 'on a circle'. But based on ellipse, I'd have a world of new challenges. Thus, really, it is a case more of 'ruling out', or 'hey', discovering this is 'not a circle'-- So, 'okay', and then dealing with it.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca See: https://openprocessing.org/sketch/1714609

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I mean despite my rather 'practical' question (I mean I *think* all, or *most* screen presses should be based on a 'radiant circle', yet if not what if ?). Yet, despite my needs/desires, the more I think about it, this becomes an 'interesting problem'. I mean, I don't have it, quite yet (I need to order some measurement equipment), but knowing dY/dX, I don't believe this is an 'unsolvable problem' I am just having a hard time 'grasping it'.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with "screen presses" and have no idea of what a "radiant circle" is. If you are interested in the abstract mathematical problem, then you should make clear what kind of data you have and what you want to find.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca well by 'radiant circle', I just mean a 'damn circle'. I am also sorry others have not chimed in, because despite my application, this seems a rather interesting 'problem'. And 'yes' I know, quite easily if I had the 'function' of the chords drawn, I could determine 'which is which'. Perhaps that is where I need to go with my next step. But, regardless, this seems an interesting question to 'think about'.

Comment: "This seems a rather interesting problem". Maybe, but what is your problem, exactly? You go on posting vague comments but your question is not clear at all, if you don't give some more details.

Comment: Question is basic: How do you determine whether any length of an arc comes from a circle, or not (?) I mean I greatly 'thank you' with giving me the thought of calculating the normals, which requires at least three points, and I can do that. My thought, or question rather, was 'certainly', mathematically, someone must have asked the question: 'Is this a circle or not ?'-- Absent of either a formula or observation.

Comment: The measurements you're taking do not determine the answer to your question: for any three noncolinear points, there is a circle that passes through them, and there are also non-circular ellipses that pass through them.

Comment: E.g. see https://www.desmos.com/calculator/p4opty5mk3 -- as you slide the slider, you will see the blue curve produces a series of ellipses that have the same chord length 8 and height 2 above the center of the chord as the red circle.  (At $b = 1$ you get a degenerate case of two lines; for $b > 1$ you would get hyperbolas.)

Comment: You construct the normal at any point by drawing a perpendicular to the tangent. If the normals meet in a point then the arc is part of a circle. If not, then not. Whether the arc is part of an ellipse or just some other arch-like thing is another question.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca, so I've been given a lot of excellent ideas here to to try and think about/solve my problem. Again, I am asking on this forum because maybe 'math has never been my strong suit'. But I know how to 'play the game'-- So, let's assume I X, Y draw out a curve (or arc I've found)-- Does any program exist today where I can slot all these coordinates in and find the resulting equation ? I mean, yes, I know I could do a polynomial regression. But that's the best idea I have. I don't know if there is something better out there ?

Comment: No, there is no magic procedure for finding equations that describe geometric curves.

Answer (score 2):

Given a curve, your question is about determining if

> ... arc is part of an ellipse, or a circle given a chord length (Cl) and height (H).

however, a comment from JBL indicates that those two measurements alone
are **not** enough to answer your question. There are alternative
measurements that are enough. Here is one example.

In any circle, if four points $\;A,B,C,D\;$ (in that order) on the circle
are equidistant (i.e., the chord lengths $\;AB, BC, CD\;$ are all equal)
then also chords $\;AC\;$ and $\;BD\;$ have the same length.
If not, then the curve is not a circle. Thus, place four equidistant points
on your curve and measure the chord lengths $\;AC\;$ and $\;BD.\;$ If the
lengths are different, then the curve is not a circle. It may or may not be
an ellipse or any other kind of curve. For more assurance, repeat this
several times with different starting point $\;A\;$ and chord lengths,
and see if you get equality of chord lengths.

Comment: This is a very good answer; a simple construction + easy-to-compute test quantity should keep the inherent experimental and measurement errors under control.

Comment: There is another fact : it is surely impossible to distinguish an arc of an ellipse with small eccentricity and an arc of circle.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t show any values. But. A vertical line from the highest point, running through line h. Then a chord from the point where your chord and the height intersect the figure. A perpendicular line from that chord’s midpoint. You now have the center of a circle, to check if in fact it’s a circle. If it’s equidistant from any other point, circle. If not, ellipse.

Answer (score 0):

Three points determine a circle.  Your diagrams show three points, the ends of the arrows, though the second one will not fit a circle.  If you have a fourth point and they are exact you can just ask if it lies on the circle defined by the other three or not.  If the points are not exact you will not be able to tell a circle from an ellipse with small eccentricity.  You can do the same as the first point-ask if the fourth point is within a certain distance from the circle.  If it is, you can do a numeric least squares to find the best fit circle.  If not, you can declare that it is not a circle and find an ellipse that fits.